# Split an event in two in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm making a scheduling-tool using FullCalendar Scheduler, and want to let the user split/slice an event in two when clicked. I'd therefore like to retrieve the date and time that user clicks when eventClick is triggered, and make the event into two events. I can't find any easy way to do this, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no built in way to detect this. You'd have to handle the click on the event, and then pop up some extra UI to ask the user for the time data, and then proceed. You could possibly request the ability to detect the clicked time as a fullCalendar feature, but due to the way it builds the HTML as a series of overlaid grids, I suspect it would actually be very difficult, if not impossible, to implement. And obviously it could only ever work on the agenda-style views anyway, since the others don't have a time grid.

Comment: Ahh, okay! Thanks for clarifying, I'd have to come up with something else then.